# Encrypting Fields when using JetBrains Exposed

Tags: encryption, kotlin, dao, jetbrains-ide

Is there a simple way to add encrypted field functionality to JetBrains Exposed database framework for Kotlin?

https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed

Answer (score 0):

Derive a SecureVarchar column type from VarCharColumnType and use this type in the table.

```
class SecureVarCharColumnType(val l: Int = 255, c: String? = null) : VarCharColumnType(l, c) {

    override fun valueToDB(value: Any?): Any? = value?.let {
        return notNullValueToDB(Crypto.encrypt(it.toString()));
    }

    override fun valueFromDB(value: Any): Any {
        return Crypto.decrypt(value.toString())
    }
}

object Users : IntIdTable("user") {
    val email = super.registerColumn<String>("email", SecureVarCharColumnType(255))
 
}
```

Comment: Your formatting is broken. You can easily edit your answer by clicking "edit".